# Get attribute information from inheriting class, inside static function

Tags: c#, static-methods, decoration, attributeusage

I have a situation where I need to get the value on a property on an attribute (decorator) applied to a class. That class that is decorated, is inheriting from an abstract class. It is this abstract class that needs to get the attribute information, but it needs to do so inside a static function.

I cannot post the exact scenario, but here is a terrible example that could do without attributes, but please work with it as it is:

```
public class VehicleShapeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Shape { get; }
    public VehicleShapeAttribute(string shape)
    {
        Shape = shape;
    }
}

public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }

    public static string GetVehicleShape()
    {
        //return value from the attribute, from this static function. CANT DO THIS HERE
        return AnyInheritingClass.VehicleShapeAttribute.Shape;
    }
}

[VehicleShape("sedan")]
public class VauxhaulAstraSedan : Vehicle
{
    //calling GetVehicleShape() on this class should automatically return "sedan"
}
```

Is this possible?

**This is a bad example but I cannot post the actual code**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the method non-static and resolve the runtime type with `this.GetType()`:

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }

    public string GetVehicleShape()
    {
        var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(this.GetType(), typeof(VehicleShapeAttribute)) as VehicleShapeAttribute;

        if(attribute is VehicleShapeAttribute){
            return attribute.Shape;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

For a static version, you'll need to accept a `Vehicle` parameter whose type you can then inspect:

```
public static string GetVehicleShape(Vehicle vehicle)
{
    var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(vehicle.GetType());
    // ...
```

Comment: I unfortunately need the context to be static. The reason for that is: in actual code I need to check that property while calling base on the constructor for the class that is decorated. I have multiple other solutions but thought I would give this approach a go for learning purposes

Comment: Mark it static, accept an arbitrary `object` (or a Vehicle) as a parameter argument and call GetType() on that, then?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively (and I'm just copy/pasting Mathias' code into another form syntactically here) if you really need to have the method `static` because you don't want to create an instance, you can add the following method to your attribute code (or any other static class, but I like to put it there with the attribute):

```
public static string GetFrom<T>()
{
    return GetFrom(typeof(T));
}

public static string GetFrom(Type t)
{
    var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(t, typeof(VehicleShapeAttribute)) as VehicleShapeAttribute;

    if(attribute is VehicleShapeAttribute){
        return attribute.Shape;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then you could write code like:

```
var shape = VehicleShapeAttribute.GetFrom<VauxhaulAstraSedan>();
```

or

```
var shape = VehicleShapeAttribute.GetFrom(typeof(VauxhaulAstraSedan));
```

or even

```
var vehicle = new VauxhaulAstraSedan();
var shape = VehicleShapeAttribute.GetFrom(vehicle.GetType());
```